# How to show message of nodata on highcharts c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I'm using Highcharts under c# .net
I want to show a message "No data to display" if the series are empty and there no graphe or data to display.

I added the code bellow but it is not shown:

```
            Lang = new Lang
            {
               NoData = "Aucune donnée à afficher",
            },
            NoData = new NoData
            {
                Style = new NoDataStyle
                {
                    FontWeight = "bold",
                    FontSize = "15px",
                    Color = "#303030",                       
                },                  
            }
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Hi @Ahmed SEDDIK, To use the `noData` feature you need to add the `no-data-to-display` module, did you do that? Example in pure JS: https://jsfiddle.net/u7kt5nx4/
How to load a module: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/your-first-chart-with-highcharts-net-and-net-core/

Comment: yes. Exactly. I should integrate the module of NoDataToDisplay. Thanks a lot